# Display an indexed image from res/raw

Tags: android

I want to display one of the images stored on res/raw folder. The matter is that the android path of my image is "R.raw.fx", with x and index (like f1, f25,...), and I don't know what will be this index. So i want to sort of append "f" and my index to store the image on a ImageView.

Any guess how i can do that ? (not the ImageView part :) ofc)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow this approach:

I make a map like this (in a static variable or inside a singleton)

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> imageIdMap;
```

When the app is loaded, i populate it:

```
imageIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

imageIdMap.put("f1", R.raw.f1);
imageIdMap.put("f2", R.raw.f2);
```

Later use like:

```
myIageView.setImageResource(imageIdMap.get("f" + index));
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I eventually have found a much simpler way to do it a few minutes ago: I set an URI pointing to "android.resource://com.myapp/raw/f"+myID, and then i use the .setImageUri()  method